# mysql/php timezone issues

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to use a timestamp for mysql entries, however it's showing up as behind 20 hours.

When I type the following into mysql command line the correct time is displayed (it's currently 8:15 PM Eastern)

```
SELECT NOW();
```

When I submit something into my database using the following, everything is correct except the time is being displayed as 12:15 am.

```
date('m/d/Y,h:i:a');
```

The column in my table is varchar(20) if that matters.

I also tried to make sure it's set to eastern timezone by using but got an error saying incorrect timezone.

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Does anyone have a clue why I'm off by 20 hours in my databse entries but when I use mysql command line to look up the time it's displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a PHP timezone issue. You should check what Timezone you have set in your PHP ini file.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

You can also set the timezone in your script:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/New_York');
```

Seems like you were trying to change the Timezone in MySQL. You should also check your timezone setting MySQL, just to make sure.

Comment: Where exactly in my script do I set this? I use a variable $timestamp = date('m/d/Y,h:i:a'); and then enter that variable. Would I set it before that variable?

Comment: Yeah just do the ini_set at the beginning of the script.

Comment: To test, just print out the date to see if it is in the correct timezone.